# Is there a way to pad incoming ByteBuf?

Tags: base64, netty, reactor-netty

I'm doing Base64 decoding, so I'm reading the input in 4 byte chunks. To make this work, I've added `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` as [mentioned in the documentation of `Base64Decoder`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/base64/Base64Decoder.java#L40C48-L40C74).

I'm concerned what happens when the last chunk is truncated (i.e. it's only 1-3 bytes instead of four).

A unit test shows that the truncated last chunk is silently ignored.

Is there a way to pad the last received ByteBuf?

If not, is there a way to see in the decoder that I'm processing the last ByteBuf of a large download?

Comment: May be you can take a look at this one https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/base64

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva The documentation mentions that I need a `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`  which I've added to my test and which made me realize I can lose bytes.